# Power BI average of averages of averages DAX measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, average, powerbi-desktop, subtotal

I have datas seems like this :

[image: example data]

We have to calculate the averages of the column "value", however we have to follow the rule : "all component have the same weight in a product, all product have the same weight in a domain, and all domain have the same weight in a platform.
The goal is to have some table like this :
[image: Goal]

So, I have to do average of the averages of products to have the Domain view.
I tried a lot of things in dax but nothing work since product level ...

I tried averagex with temp table but I don't know why this doesn't work.

[image: Doesn't work]

```
measure = VAR comp = SUMMARIZE('table','table'[Platform],'table'[Domain],'table'[product_id],'K8S deployments'[component_name],"K1",CALCULATE(AVERAGEX('table',[Value])))
VAR prod = SUMMARIZE(comp,[Platform],[Domain],[product_id],"K1P",AVERAGEX(comp,[K1]))
VAR dom = SUMMARIZE(prod,[Platform],[Domain],"K1D",AVERAGEX(prod,[K1P]))
VAR plat = SUMMARIZE(dom,[Platform],"K1P",AVERAGEX(dom,[K1D]))
return AVERAGEX(plat,[K1P])
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Small sample dataset in markdown format with expected results would be useful.

Comment: | Platform | Domain    | Product   | Component | AVG   |
|------|--------|--------|------|-------|
| PDP  | Legacy | basa   | A    | 6,99  |
| PDP  | Legacy | basa   | C    | 4     |
| PDP  | truc   | bizi   | F    | 8     |
| PDP  | truc   | pegase | A    | 20,25 |
| PDP  | truc   | pegase | C    | 6,75  |
| PDP  | truc   | pegase | D    | 10,13 |
| CCDP | Care   | campus | A    | 13,38 |
| CCDP | Care   | Med    | A    | 1,36  |
| CCDP | Care   | Med    | B    | 4,6   |
| CCDP | Cure   | Med    | C    | 6,63  |
| CCDP | Cure   | Med    | D    | 0,9   |

Comment: The expected results is a matrix visual with Platform-domain-product-component levels in rows and the average value in values